# Show that every prime factor of $4t^2 + 1$ is equivalent to 1 modulo 4

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, prime-numbers, congruences, prime-factorization

Show every prime factor of $4t^2 + 1$ is equivalent to 1 modulo 4

My working so far:

I want to use the first Nebensatz, so given q is a prime factor I want to show $(-1/q)=(-1)^{(q-1)/2}=1$ as this implies $q \equiv1 (mod  4)$

It would be sufficient to prove $x^2=-1 (mod 4t^2 +1)$ has solutions as we could then use Chinese remainder to imply the above, however I'm not sure how to prove this has solutions.

Comment: Just try a bit more, $x^2 + 1 = 4t^2+1$.

Comment: Thanks that helped, I see how to do it! @DanielFischer

Comment: @DanielFischer Here is another possible comment -> answer.

Comment: @JulianKuelshammer Done.

Answer (score 1):

Occasionally, it is easier to (see how to) prove a stronger assertion than the required assertion.

If we try to find a solution of the equation $x^2 + 1 = 4t^2 + 1$ rather than a solution of the congruence $x^2 \equiv -1 \pmod{4t^2+1}$, the solution $x = 2t$ immediately jumps out. Hence a fortiori $(2t)^2 \equiv -1 \pmod{q}$ for every prime factor $q$ of $4t^2+1$, which shows $q\equiv 1 \pmod{4}$.